# elastic error while setting mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting this error while trying to set mapping..

Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes

```
XContentBuilder mapping = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject("mydocuments")
                    .startObject("mytype")
                    .startObject("properties")
                    .startObject("blob_field")
                    .field("type", "string")
                    .field("index", "not_analyzed")
                    .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                    .endObject();
            PutMappingResponse putMappingResponse = client.admin().indices()
                    .preparePutMapping("mydocuments")
                    .setType("mytype")
                    .setSource(mapping)
                    .execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you print your request body and try it in command line? Try to print this:

```
client.admin().indices()
                .preparePutMapping("mydocuments")
                .setType("mytype")
                .setSource(mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this with Elasticsearch 2.0? In 2.0 they no longer shade dependencies. Add the required Jackson dependencies to your classpath and the error may be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your mapping object to a string first

```
XContentBuilder mapping = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                .startObject("mydocuments")
                .startObject("mytype")
                .startObject("properties")
                .startObject("blob_field")
                .field("type", "string")
                .field("index", "not_analyzed")
                .endObject()
                .endObject()
                .endObject()
                .endObject();

        PutMappingResponse putMappingResponse = client.admin().indices()
                .preparePutMapping("mydocuments")
                .setType("mytype")
                .setSource(mapping.string())      <---- transform to string
                .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: @user3549576 have you been able to try this?